# How to use Java-8 default-interface-implementation in a OSGi-Service

Tags: osgi, java-8, apache-karaf

I would like to use Java 8 features on the latest Apache-Karaf release (3.0.2) which is supposed to support Java 8.

I have a service-interface within my domain-layer (repository) which has a default-method for identity-generation

```
public interface MyRepository{

    ...

    default MyId nextIdentity() {
        return new MyId(UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Then I have a Implementation of that interface which is exposed as a OSGi-Service using Blueprint (Apache-Aries).

When I run my application the bundles get installed successfully, the services get registered, but when the application-layer is calling the method nextIdentity I get a Exception.

```
IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface MyRepository, but class was expected
```

The application-layer is straight forward: Interface-Attribute which gets its class (in this case OSGi-Service-Reference) injected via Blueprint.

I did check the compilation: all modules are compiled with Java 8 compliance level in Eclipse. I am guessing the problem is related to a aries-proxy which is not Java 8, but since karaf supports it....

EDIT: added Stacktrace

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public bikeshop.http.wicket.page.GaragePage()'. Might be it doesn't exist, may be it is not visible (public).
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:193)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:66)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.wicket.internal.PaxWicketPageFactory.newPage(PaxWicketPageFactory.java:76)[100:org.ops4j.pax.wicket.service:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:133)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:268)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:166)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:244)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:165)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:854)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)[91:org.apache.wicket.request:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:254)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:211)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:282)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91ca4a1b.CGLIB$processRequestCycle$4(<generated>)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91ca4a1b$$FastClassByCGLIB$$36c566fa.invoke(<generated>)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)[99:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib:2.2.2.1]
    at org.ops4j.pax.wicket.internal.servlet.PAXWicketServlet$WicketFilterCallback.intercept(PAXWicketServlet.java:150)[100:org.ops4j.pax.wicket.service:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91ca4a1b.processRequestCycle(<generated>)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91ca4a1b.CGLIB$processRequest$12(<generated>)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91ca4a1b$$FastClassByCGLIB$$36c566fa.invoke(<generated>)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)[99:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib:2.2.2.1]
    at org.ops4j.pax.wicket.internal.servlet.PAXWicketServlet$WicketFilterCallback.intercept(PAXWicketServlet.java:150)[100:org.ops4j.pax.wicket.service:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91ca4a1b.processRequest(<generated>)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91ca4a1b.CGLIB$doFilter$10(<generated>)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91ca4a1b$$FastClassByCGLIB$$36c566fa.invoke(<generated>)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)[99:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cglib:2.2.2.1]
    at org.ops4j.pax.wicket.internal.servlet.PAXWicketServlet$WicketFilterCallback.intercept(PAXWicketServlet.java:150)[100:org.ops4j.pax.wicket.service:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$91ca4a1b.doFilter(<generated>)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    at org.ops4j.pax.wicket.internal.servlet.PAXWicketServlet.service(PAXWicketServlet.java:98)[100:org.ops4j.pax.wicket.service:3.0.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.wicket.internal.filter.PAXWicketFilterChain.doFilter(PAXWicketFilterChain.java:61)[100:org.ops4j.pax.wicket.service:3.0.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.wicket.internal.filter.FilterDelegator.doFilter(FilterDelegator.java:82)[100:org.ops4j.pax.wicket.service:3.0.2]
    at org.ops4j.pax.wicket.internal.servlet.ServletCallInterceptor.service(ServletCallInterceptor.java:168)[100:org.ops4j.pax.wicket.service:3.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)[80:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:240)[80:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:77)[80:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.1.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[71:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.15.v20140411]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)[:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)[:1.8.0_20]
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:174)[92:org.apache.wicket.core:6.7.0]
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface bikeshop.domain.repository.BikeRepository, but class was expected
    at Proxy04d92f46_988d_4726_9355_6b6381790fde.nextIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at bikeshop.application.service.BikeApplicationService.loadGarage(BikeApplicationService.java:22)
    at Proxyc25af47a_a344_4a1b_8d0e_429a76d453c6.loadGarage(Unknown Source)
    at Proxy163e0a74_12bc_4124_827b_2119133222e8.loadGarage(Unknown Source)
    at bikeshop.presentation.internal.GaragePresentationService.init(GaragePresentationService.java:21)
    at Proxy5a3bd46a_6830_438c_b5eb_0ca9ec091479.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)[:1.8.0_20]
    at org.ops4j.pax.wicket.util.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:253)
    at org.ops4j.pax.wicket.util.proxy.$Proxy22.init(Unknown Source)
    at bikeshop.http.wicket.page.GaragePage.<init>(GaragePage.java:30)
```

Comment: Sounds like at least one component does *not* support Java 8 correctly.

Comment: I guess that it is aries-proxy. However, it is hard to find it out the real cause without a stacktrace.

Comment: Usually I dont like adding Stacktraces because I dont want to burden somebody else with it, and because I thought I missed some important detail :)
In this case thought it is probably better to provide one.

Comment: "Proxy04d92f46_988d_4726_9355_6b6381790fde.nextIdentity(Unknown Source)": That is what I really like in magical technologies :)

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos just read your thoughts about "magic" in your transaction-helper project https://github.com/everit-org/transaction-helper Very interesting and worth a try

Comment: well, I guess we should have been more clearer with the Java8 support. It's runnable with Java8 JVM but not all new features of Java8 are always usable. Especially with Aries Blueprint being compiled with JDK7 and made sure it's backward compatible to JDK6. New specialties only runnable with JDK8 are not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit here is probably Blueprint, which generates a proxy class for every imported service, rather than giving you the service object directly. I don't believe that Aries Blueprint has been updated for Java 8 compatibility.

The solution would be to avoid Blueprint and use something like Declarative Services (DS), which is much closer to "real" OSGi Services and gives your consumer the actual service instance. DS definitely works with Java 8 interfaces having default methods.

Comment: I used DS in the begining, but switched to Blueprint for the karaf-jpa examples.

The reason for Blueprint is actually driven by my requirements: integrate JPA. I know that the OSGi-community is not happy about Blueprint but coming from standard JEE I need a slow migration from "Standards" (Spring, JPA, ...) to OSGi. As far as I know, DS can only inject OSGi-Services (and I guess that it is probably better to ask for a service than to compose classes with injection), but for a slow migration it is necessary to provide some bean-injection as well. 
So much for the off-topic requirements :-)

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, I don't see Blueprint anywhere. I do see Pax Wicket proxy: `org.ops4j.pax.wicket.util.proxy`. So this could be a Pax Wicket issue with Java 8 rather than Blueprint.

Comment: If you're looking for JPA support in a more pure OSGi way, take a look at Amdatu JPA: http://amdatu.org/components/jpa.html. No need for blueprint :)

Comment: Thanks for the Amdatu-Link. I've also found the enRoute-examples ( https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute.blog/tree/10-jpa ) quite interesting...I just have to figure out how bndtools resolves the dependencies via JPM. In my example I copied everything in the Local-Repo

Answer (score 0):

Update:

This issue seems to be fixed in the proxy-impl 1.1.4 of Aries / Karaf 4.2.3

[KARAF-6087](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-6087)

[ARIES-1849](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARIES-1849)